# Prove that $K\le G$ of finite index and $[G:K]=[G:H][H:K]$ for infinite $G$ with $H\le G$ and $K\le H$.

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be an infinite group. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ of finite index and $K$ is a subgroup of $H$ of finite index. Prove that $K$ is subgroup of $G$ of finite index and $[G:K]=[G:H][H:K].$

If $G$ is finite, then the problem is easy. But what to do for infinite $G$?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have an element $g\in G$. Then $gK$ is contained in the coset $gH$. If $h_1,h_2\in H$, consider $a\in gh_1K$ and $b\in gh_2K$. Then $a^{-1}b\in K$ if and only if $h_1^{-1}g^{-1}gh_2=h_1^{-1}h_2\in K$. Thus the coset $gH$ is the disjoint union of cosets $ghK$ for $h\in H$, which correspond bijectively to the cosets $hK$ for $h\in H$.

There are $[G:H] $ cosets of $H$ and $[H:K] $ cosets of $K$ in $H$. Thus there are $[G:H] [H:K] $ cosets of $K$ in $G$, hence in particular it is of finite index.